# Create a single pandas.core.frame.Pandas object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I create a single row of data as a `pandas.core.frame.Pandas object`?

So, when you iterate a dataframe (df) with `for row in df.itertuples()`, each row will be a `pandas.core.frame.Pandas` object.  I want to create an object of that type.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(type(df))
print("a", df.a)

for row in df.itertuples():
    print(type(row))
    print("a", row.a)


myrow = None
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
for row in df.itertuples():
    myrow = row
print(type(myrow))
print("a", myrow.a)
```

Its output is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
a 0    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>
a 1
<class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>
a 1
```

As you can see, `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` acts differenctly as `pandas.core.frame.Pandas`, as expected.

I dont really want to create `myrow` the way I did above, so I was wondering whats the more efficient/direct way to create that object.  Assuming I only have 1 list of data I want to convert to `pandas.core.frame.Pandas` object

Comment: Why? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It's just a tuple subclass created using  the `collections.namedtuple` factory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Explanation:

Every iteration of `itertuples` gives an object like:

```
Pandas(Index=0, a=1, b=2)
```

`Pandas` is just the default name of the `itertuples` `name` argument, example:

```
>>> help(df.itertuples)
Help on method itertuples in module pandas.core.frame:

itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas') method of pandas.core.frame.DataFrame instance
    Iterate over DataFrame rows as namedtuples.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    index : bool, default True
        If True, return the index as the first element of the tuple.
    name : str or None, default "Pandas"
        The name of the returned namedtuples or None to return regular
        tuples.
```

The default name is `Pandas`. That is just the name of the `namedtuple`.

If you change that name, the types would become different:

```
for row in df.itertuples(name='newname'):
    print(row)
    print(type(row))
    print("a", row.a)
```

Output:

```
newname(Index=0, a=1, b=2)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.newname'>
a 1
```

## Replication:

This is the default behavior of `namedtuple`s, example:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> a = namedtuple('Pandas', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>> a(1, 2, 3)
Pandas(x=1, y=2, z=3)
>>> type(_)
<class '__main__.Pandas'>
>>>
```

As you can see, the type of this is `Pandas`, which is the type name of this `namedtuple`, so `itertuples` doesn't give a `Pandas` object, instead it's just the default set name of the `itertuples` `namedtuple` output.

## Documentation reference:

As mentioned in the [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) documentation:

> Returns a new tuple subclass named *typename*. The new subclass is used to create tuple-like objects that have fields accessible by attribute lookup as well as being indexable and iterable. Instances of the subclass also have a helpful docstring (with typename and field_names) and a helpful `__repr__()` method which lists the tuple contents in a `name=value` format.

As you can see, it creates a new type.

Comment: Started answering long back but instead of searching the code could have searched simple documentation. Lesson learnt..Good answer by the way.

Comment: Well I can't deny that but some times they have an abstraction which for some people is helpful but sometimes properly commented source code is even better *to me*. Maybe I should try to change that.

Comment: @user2736738 Yeap! That's better!

Answer (score 0):

To understand the thing better, I checked the source [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6161f67d1d5886838fa968e42158e675ac987970/pandas/core/frame.py#L1287). And it seems it's just the default name passed to the `collections.namedtuple()` factory to create a named `tuple`. This [line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6161f67d1d5886838fa968e42158e675ac987970/pandas/core/frame.py#L1355) also emphasizes what I said.

Here is a funny example to prove what I said:

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(type(df))
print("a", df.a)

for row in df.itertuples():
    print(type(row))
    print("a", row.a)


myrow = None
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
for row in df.itertuples(name="user"):
    myrow = row
print(type(myrow))
print("a", myrow.a)
```

Output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
a 0    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>
a 1
<class 'pandas.core.frame.user'>
a 1
```